# Use JDBC driver to connect to database

Tags: google-apps-script, jdbc, database-connection

I'm trying to use a script in Google Sheets to connect to a database via the getConnection(url, userName, password) method (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getconnectionurl,-username,-password) but I keep getting an error saying "Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password."

I'm being told by support that "Google Sheets isn't supported with the database as JDBC drivers are set to connect to TLS 1.0. Currently TLS 1.2 is set for our environments as a security requirement." but I'm seeing information online that says otherwise.

Am I just understanding this issue wrong? Is there a way to use TLS 1.2 with Google Scripts?

Comment: Can you share the SQL database you're using?

Comment: Can you also share the MySQL/SQL version?

Comment: Hey @IrvinJayG. I can't share the database I'm using.

Comment: There is not really enough information in the question to provide help, without guesswork. Can you [edit] your question and provide a [mre]?